# Cannot get a kubernetes node to connect to master in Vagrant/Ansible

Tags: kubernetes

I'm currently trying to learn Kubernetes by creating a Vagrant/Ansible project that allows me to bring up a master and node(s) and I've run into some problems. I'm currently use `kubeadm` to run the `init` and `join` function. For the `init`, I'm parsing the command line output to get the token (which I know is terrible; is there a more standard way to do this?):

```
---
  - command: kubeadm init
    args:
      creates: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
    register: kube_init

  - local_action: copy content={{ kube_init.stdout_lines[-1].split()[-2] }} dest=../kube.token
    when: kube_init is defined

  - local_action: copy content={{ kube_init.stdout_lines[-1].split()[-1] }} dest=../kube.master_ip
    when: kube_init is defined
```

Source: https://gitlab.com/djsumdog/skube/blob/0e25fca668e1067a8aa4af59b019411303838e86/ansible/roles/master/tasks/main.yml

But it works. The trouble is, I can't get the node to connect:

```
TASK: [node | command kubeadm join --token=1a3131.637de46bfdebadd4 10.0.2.15] *** 
failed: [node1] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["kubeadm", "join", "--token=1a3131.637de46bfdebadd4", "10.0.2.15"], "delta": "0:00:00.079545", "end": "2016-10-25 01:54:51.858545", "rc": 1, "start": "2016-10-25 01:54:51.779000", "warnings": []}
stderr: error: <node/discovery> failed to request cluster info [Get http://10.0.2.15:9898/cluster-info/v1/?token-id=1a3131: dial tcp 10.0.2.15:9898: getsockopt: connection refused]
stdout: <util/tokens> validating provided token
<node/discovery> created cluster info discovery client, requesting info from "http://10.0.2.15:9898/cluster-info/v1/?token-id=1a3131"

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I can ping my master VM from the node VM and I can even ssh to it. It appears as if the kubernetes services are all running on the master too:

```
$ systemctl status kubelet.service 
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-10-25 01:51:35 UTC; 13h ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 5726 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 15
   Memory: 45.5M
      CPU: 11min 37.179s
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           ├─5726 /usr/bin/kubelet --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --require-kubeconfig=true --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cluster-
           └─5740 journalctl -k -f

Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532171    5726 factory.go:108] Factory "systemd" can handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-kubelet-pods-9d0e93cd\\x2d9a55\\x2d11e6\\x2db2dd\\x2d02558d159192-volumes-kubernetes.io\\x7esecret-default\\
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532175    5726 manager.go:843] ignoring container "/system.slice/var-lib-kubelet-pods-9d0e93cd\\x2d9a55\\x2d11e6\\x2db2dd\\x2d02558d159192-volumes-kubernetes.io\\x7esecret-default\\x2dtoken\\x2ddn3r9.m
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532184    5726 factory.go:104] Error trying to work out if we can handle /system.slice/run-docker-netns-default.mount: invalid container name
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532187    5726 factory.go:115] Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/run-docker-netns-default.mount"
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532190    5726 factory.go:108] Factory "systemd" can handle container "/system.slice/run-docker-netns-default.mount", but ignoring.
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532194    5726 manager.go:843] ignoring container "/system.slice/run-docker-netns-default.mount"
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532316    5726 factory.go:104] Error trying to work out if we can handle /system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay-6d625f0d241bc6ae9eb243b430a71f078912a76147fc51e41e8e6e5f3226c6e9-merged.mount: error inspec
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532321    5726 factory.go:115] Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay-6d625f0d241bc6ae9eb243b430a71f078912a76147fc51e41e8e6e5f3226c6e9-merged.mount"
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532325    5726 factory.go:108] Factory "systemd" can handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay-6d625f0d241bc6ae9eb243b430a71f078912a76147fc51e41e8e6e5f3226c6e9-merged.mount", but ignoring.
Oct 25 15:43:35 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[5726]: I1025 15:43:35.532330    5726 manager.go:843] ignoring container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay-6d625f0d241bc6ae9eb243b430a71f078912a76147fc51e41e8e6e5f3226c6e9-merged.mount"
```

Why is my master not listening for connections? Here is the exact commit I'm using:

https://gitlab.com/djsumdog/skube/tree/0e25fca668e1067a8aa4af59b019411303838e86

If you have ansible and vagrant installed, you should be able to run `vagrant up` and get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was due to my Vagrant setup. Both VMs were getting the same IP address. I needed to specify a `:private_network` and an `ip:` in my Vagrantfile:

```
...
config.vm.define "master" do |master|
  master.vm.network :private_network, ip: 10.10.30.10
...
...
config.vm.define "node1" do |node1|
  node1.vm.network :private_network, :ip: 10.10.30.50
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try executing following commands after *kubeadm init* and before *kubeadm join*

```
kubectl taint nodes --all dedicated-
kubectl apply -f <add-on.yaml>
```

Refer this page http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

Comment: `kubectl taint` allows pods to be deployed on the master node which is has nothing to do with joining nodes to the cluster and this would still cause the above issue.